# How can I make python ruaml preserve long strings as is?

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I'm using ruamel.yaml to do round trip load/dump, but on some files with hand-crafted strings, I would like to preserve them. Sometimes this is nice because the formatting is actually pretty (readability), or copy/paste ability.

Here is my code:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
import sys
yaml = YAML()

i = """
mydict:
  command: "my_shell_script
    --firstarg
    --second
    --third
    .......
    fourth
  "
"""

data = yaml.load(i)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

Which outputs

```
mydict:
  command: 'my_shell_script --firstarg --second --third ....... fourth '
```

I *don't* want it to change those lines. I'm familiar with the `yaml.width` option, but I don't want to set that at all! (high or low).

How can I make ruamel.yaml preserve the formatting on scalars like this? Does it have anything to do with `PreservedScalarString`? Can I do it such a way that it preserves only certain scalars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hook into the double quoted scalar string loading/construction, you
would probably have to set `yaml.preserve_quotes`, and then have that behave
like the loader for folded scalars.

But it is much easier to use YAML's folded scalars in the first place, as that
looks quite like your input, round-trips out of the box. And only differs in the
loaded value in that there is no trailing space (which I hope is not
significant):

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """
mydict:
  command: "my_shell_script
    --firstarg
    --second
    --third
    .......
    fourth
    "
altdict:
  command: >-
    my_shell_script
    --firstarg
    --second
    --third
    .......
    fourth
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
for k in data:
    print(repr(data[k]['command']))
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
'my_shell_script --firstarg --second --third ....... fourth '
'my_shell_script --firstarg --second --third ....... fourth'
mydict:
  command: 'my_shell_script --firstarg --second --third ....... fourth '
altdict:
  command: >-
    my_shell_script
    --firstarg
    --second
    --third
    .......
    fourth
```

As you can see the folded scalar dumps as the input.

If you leave the `-` from `>-`, you'll get a (single) newline at the end of your loaded data.